# Clipping a polygon to only draw within a circle in Love2D

Tags: graphics, lua, drawing, love2d

I'm trying to draw a circle with filled, randomly generated polygons drawn on top of it, but I can't work out how to make it so that the polygons are only drawn on top of the circle.

Here's a mockup as an example:

[image]

I have a achieved the random polygons drawn on a circle, using the `love.graphics.polygon()` function with a set of randomly generated points, but I'm looking for a way of clipping them when they're drawn so that they're only filled in on top of the circle.

Here's what I've actually got so far:

[image]

So, my question is: is there a function that I can call in the `love.draw` function that clips parts of the polygon drawn outside of a range, or is it going to be harder to fix than that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, I may have just found the answer. I'll post it when I get a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I could have just spent a minute looking at the `love.graphics` documentation. Anyway, the [`love.graphics.stencil()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.stencil) function and its counterpart `love.graphics.setStencilTest()` are just what I needed.

You can pass the draw function for the circle to the `love.graphics.stencil()` function, and the using the `setStencilTest()`, you can make it not draw pixels outside that circle function. The documentation has some good examples.

Here is a simple example with a camera centered on the screen with a mask only allowing the background grid to be drawn within the circle. Use motion keys to move the camera.

```
function love.load()
  camera_x = 0
  camera_y = 0
end

function love.draw()
  local width, height = love.graphics.getDimensions()

  love.graphics.stencil(function()
    love.graphics.circle("fill", width / 2, height / 2, math.min(width*2/3, height*2/3) / 2)
  end, "replace", 1)

  love.graphics.setStencilTest("greater", 0)

  -- draw a grid to see the camera movement
  for x = 0, width, 50 do
    local x = x - camera_x % 50
    love.graphics.line(x, 0, x, height)

    for y = 0, height, 50 do
      local y = y - camera_y % 50
      love.graphics.line(0, y, width, y)
    end
  end
end

function love.update(dt)
  if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
    camera_y = camera_y - 100 * dt * 2
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
    camera_y = camera_y + 100 * dt * 2
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
    camera_x = camera_x - 100 * dt * 2
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
    camera_x = camera_x + 100 * dt * 2
  end
end
```